Unity3d: gun pick up system doesn't work properly
I had Dani's FPS movement.
I tried to follow this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kKLUsn7tcg
But the gun did not move exactly as the video showed.
this is the image.
i tried downloading the script in the description.
i hope you guys can give me a reason for this.

Note that this isn't a general help forum, you'll need to take a moment to read the posting guidelines and then [edit] your post to explain what you set out to do, what code you wrote to do that (and why), ideally included in your post in [mcve] form, and rather importantly: what debugging and (re)searching you already did to understand where in the code things go wrong (even if you don't understand what is going wrong). Just "I followed someone's tutorial and it doesn't work" is not a Stackoverflow question (yet).

(also note that for Unity and game dev questions, https://gamedev.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask, but remember to read their rules as well)
